# 親画面が子画面の値を見る方法

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

```
myModule.controller('manager_information_controller', function($scope, member){

    //親画面から呼ばれる関数
    $scope.showModalForMemberInformation = function(){

        modal_manager.show();            
        $scope.test = "11";
    }

    //子（モーダル）画面から呼ばれる関数
    $scope.selectMembers = function(){

        modal_manager.hide();
        $scope.test = "22";

}

<!-- ページ --＞
<ons-page id="manager_information" ng-controller="manager_information_controller">

{{newGuest}}

<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-click="showModalForMember()">
モーダルへ
</ons-list-item>    

</ons-page>

<!-- モーダル -->
<ons-modal var="modal_manager" ng-controller="manager_information_controller">
        <ons-button ng-click="selectMembers()">検索</ons-button>
</ons-modal>
```

親画面が子画面の値を見る方法が分からなくて、困っています。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あるコントローラーからons-modal中のコントローラーの値を見たいということで大丈夫でしょうか。あるコントローラーから別のコントローラーに値を渡したいのであれば、少なくとも方法は2つあります。

- 一つはAngularJSのサービスを使って値を渡す方法です。あるサービスを作ってそのサービスを2つの両方のコントローラーにインジェクションします。1つ目のコントローラーで値を入力して、モーダル内のコントローラーで値を受け取ることができます。詳細は下の例をみてください。

詳細コード:

```
//サービスを作ります。
myApp.factory('SharedData', function () {
    return { example: 'example' };
});

//コントローラーを作ってサービスをインジェクションします。親画面
myApp.controller('ParentScreenController', function( $scope, SharedData ){
    $scope.Data = SharedData;
});

//コントローラーを作ってサービスをインジェクションします。子画面   
myApp.controller('ChildScreenController', function( $scope, SharedData ){
    $scope.Data = SharedData;
});
```

- もう一つはイベントを発行して値を渡す方法です。 1つ目のコントローラーでイベントを発行することによって、他のコントローラーにそのイベントとともに値を渡すことができます。簡単ですが、例を用意しました(注意: $rootScopeを両方のコントローラーにインジェクションして下さい) 。

詳細:

```
// イベントおよび値を発行するコントローラー 子画面
myApp.controller('FirstController', function( $scope, SharedData, $rootScope ){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('updatingData', sharedData);
    alert('updatingDataイベントを発行しました!');
});

// イベントおよび値を受け取るコントローラー 親画面
myApp.controller('SecondController', function( $scope, SharedData, $rootScope ){   
    $rootScope.$on('updatingData', function(event, sharedData) {
        alert('イベント受信完了!');
        $scope.sharedData = sharedData;
    });
});
```

お役に立てれば嬉しいです。

Comment: 大変参考になりました。ありがとうございました。
自己解決しました。
var testScope = angular.element(tag_id_name).scope();
や
$scope.$parent
で欲しいスコープを取得でき、そこから値を取得できました。